# How to add an array into mongodb by uing node js and angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

My Code:

```
var user = new User({
    fullname: req.body.fullname,
    mobile:req.body.mobile,
    email: req.body.email,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    state: req.body.state,
    city: req.body.city,
    pincode:req.body.pincode,
    college: req.body.college,
    course: req.body.course,
    descipline: req.body.descipline,
    semester: req.body.semester,
    university: req.body.university,
    month:req.body.month,
    worklocation:req.body.worklocation,
    members:members
});

user.save(function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    res.status(201).json(data);
});
```

Comment: where would you like to add an array ?

Comment: can you clearly explain your problem?

Comment: i want to add an array with elements into mongodb database ..I am using nodejs as middleware and angular for view..

Comment: var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    fullname: String,
    mobile:String,
    email: String,
    gender: String,
    state: String,
    city: String,
    pincode:String,
    college: String,
    course: String,
    descipline: String,
    semester: String,
    university: String,
    month:String,
    worklocation: String,
     summery: String,
    members:[{degree_name:String,degree_subject:String}]
   
   

}); this is my schema

Answer (score 0):

you can assign member array of object directly in your schema

```
var members = [{degree_name:'xxx', degree_subject: 'yyy'},
              {degree_name:'xxx1', degree_subject: 'yyy1'}];

var user = new User({
            fullname: req.body.fullname,
            .....
            members:members
        });
```

if you send same property name from angular then you can just use `req.body` like `new User(req.body)`.

so you can send as req body from UI like

```
$scope.user = {
            fullname: 'xx',
            mobile: 'yy',
            members: [{degree_name:'xxx', degree_subject: 'yyy'},
                  {degree_name:'xxx1', degree_subject: 'yyy1'}]
};
```

then in mongoose can use like

```
var user = new User(req.body);
```

then automatically mapped according to you property name.

If anything different with `req.body` property name with schema then reassign that property.

```
var user = new User(req.body); 
user.course = req.body.courseName
```

Angular code:

```
$scope.members = [{degree_name:'xxx', degree_subject: 'yyy'},
              {degree_name:'xxx1', degree_subject: 'yyy1'}];
  $scope.registerDetails = function() {
    $scope.user.members = $scope.members;
    $http.post('/api', $scope.user).success(function(data) {
      // your code
    }).error(function(status) {
      // your code
    });
  };
```

Comment: i want to save data throush angular to mongodb as an array ??

Comment: yes you can send members data as array of object @AswaniVs

Comment: Can you give full example?

Comment: var app= angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial','ngMessages']);
            app.controller('AppCntrl', function($scope, $http, $location) {
         $scope.title = "Register";

    $scope.members=[];
    $scope.registerDetails = function() {
        $http.post('/api',$scope.user).success(function(data) {
            $scope.user = data;
            $location.path('/');
            alert('Registered successfully!');
        }).error(function(status) {
            alert('Wrongly entered. Please check!');
            console.log('Error: ' + status);
        });
    };

Comment: can you give full project